# CSS - centering image and header

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hello I have been trying to create a banner, where the heading and image are centered horizontally and vertically in their div box. It works normally when there is no image however when I place an image, the image stays correctly centered whereas the heading becomes out of position as shown by the snippet. I am not sure how to solve this.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

header {
  background-color: #595959;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 300px;
}

#banner {
  margin: auto;
}

#banner h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="banner">
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/uploads/monthly_2017_08/image.jpg.31a662f3a122c7509c42474ce5346aeb.jpg" alt="Logo">
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add display: flex and align-items: center to your #banner

from

```
#banner{
margin: auto;
}
```

to

```
#banner {
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this way, if you know the image size you can edit H1 properties.

```css
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
    
body{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 3px solid red;
}
header{
background-color: #595959;
color: #fff;
display: flex;
min-height: 300px;
}
#banner{
margin: auto;
}
#banner h1{
display: block;
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div id="banner">
   <h1>Test</h1>
   <img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/uploads/monthly_2017_08/image.jpg.31a662f3a122c7509c42474ce5346aeb.jpg" alt="Logo">
  </div>
 </header>
```